# If db query A does not return enough results, run query B: how to optimize?

Tags: php, mysql, refactoring

I am looking for a good design pattern, or best practice to achieve a situation of "either this query, or else that other query", with best performance and least overhead.

Business logic/program of demans says "all items since Foo", unless that returns less then three items, then "all items". 
I am refactoring the current code, and cannot come up with a good way to achieve this logic.

Current pseudo-code (Drupal/PHP):

```
<?php
$result = db_query(
'SELECT n.uid FROM og_ancestry oga ' .
'INNER JOIN node n on n.nid = oga.nid ' .
'WHERE oga.group_nid = %d AND n.created > %d GROUP BY n.uid ' .
'ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT %d', $group_nid, $since, $limit);


while ($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
  $uids[] = $row['uid'];
}

if (count($uids) < 3) {
  $result = db_query(
    'SELECT n.uid FROM og_ancestry oga ' .
    'INNER JOIN node n on n.nid = oga.nid ' .
    'WHERE oga.group_nid = %d GROUP BY n.uid ' .
    'ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT %d', $group_nid, $limit);

  while ($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
    $uids[] = $row['uid'];
  }
}
//...do something with the result.
?>
```

This code feels "not right", first of all because of DRY: it contains the same query, with one minor difference. I can change that by a bit smarter query-building.

But worse is the fact that I need to hammer the database (query is quite heavy) only to find out that in more then half of the cases, I need to throw away the result and query the db again.

How would you approach such a case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, as you say, "in more then half of the cases, I need to throw away the result and query the db again," then your best bet may be to run **only** the second query and then evaluate the resultant dataset locally, discarding records if appropriate.  It's really more a matter of moving the complexity around than it is of reducing complexity, but at least there's just one trip to the database.

If you `ORDER BY n.created DESC`, the filtering could simply look at the third record, and if it's earlier than foo, you're done; otherwise, you need to find the first record before foo and discard it and subsequent records.

Comment: I have benchmarked it a little. And indeed. Filtering in code is by far the fastest. esp since I enforce a LIMIT 5 anyways, so at most I discard 2 items.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know - it's always nice to know what worked, out of all the answers we get on SO.  And it's nice that what felt like a good simple answer also turns out to be performant.  Sometimes we luck out!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single [CASE/WHEN query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/case-statement.html) to see if the first query returns enough. If so, use the THEN block. If not use the ELSE block. That would save you the second roundtrip to the database.

Comment: I have played around with CASE/WHENs but I cannot find a way to get either CASE WHEN count(*) < 3 WHERE A = X WHEN count (*) >= 3 WHERE B = Y. Probably I don't understand CASE/WHERE, but AFAIK it cannot be used to switch between differen WHERE clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Would one query with `ORDER BY n.created DESC, cnt DESC LIMIT 3` work?  It will get the most recently created items first, and return no more than 3 of them.  It's not *exactly* the same as what you have above, but it's pretty close...

Comment: I need it exactly the other way around: if the first returns LESS then 3, then run the second one. 
The result, then, always has MORE then 3 results.